# Linking .res file with an Executable (CMake)

Tags: c++, cmake, resources, versioninfo

i've been trying to link compiled .res file with CMake for some time, i searched internet but there is no much info bout it.
I tried adding this into my CMakeList.txt

```
SET(RESOURCE_FILE scac.res)
file(GLOB src_files 
"${RESOURCE_FILE}"
ADD_EXECUTABLE( FOO ${FOO_SRCS} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( FOO ${FOO_LIBS} )
SET( FOO_LINKFLAGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/scac-module/scac.res )
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( FOO PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${FOO_LINKFLAGS} )
)
```

.res file contains `VERSIONINFO` and also `ICON`, CMAKE doesn't give any error after compiling, and . res file is also succesfully compiled without any error, but simply version info doesn't show on application
Note: I don't have much experience with cmake, problem may be simple, or complicated

Thanks for your time, and help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the res file (although it might need to have the `.rc` extension instead) to your `$FOO_SRCS` ?

Comment: @Botje i did, but nothing happened, everything still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 6 hours, problem is solved just added `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res.rc"` into line

```
 add_executable(${EXAMPLE_TARGET} ${EXAMPLE_HEADER_FILES} ${EXAMPLE_INLINE_FILES} "examples/${EXAMPLE_SOURCE_FILE}"
```

to finally get

```
add_executable(${EXAMPLE_TARGET} ${EXAMPLE_HEADER_FILES} ${EXAMPLE_INLINE_FILES} "examples/${EXAMPLE_SOURCE_FILE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resource.rc"
```